# Powershell script gives wrong Windows Updates information

Tags: powershell, windows-update

I have the below script to detect Windows Updates that are not installed, however it always says IsDownloaded = false, but they are downloaded, I have windows updates set to Download Only. Anyone know why its not returning the correct info?

```
$updatesession =  [activator]::CreateInstance([type]::GetTypeFromProgID("Microsoft.Update.Session"))
$updatesearcher = $updatesession.CreateUpdateSearcher()
$searchresult = $updatesearcher.Search("IsInstalled=0")
$searchresult
```

I am using windows server 2016.

Comment: How do you know it is downloaded?

Comment: How can I verify if they have been downloaded, and if they haven't then how do I find out why, when Windows updates is set to download only?

Comment: You can check the Windows Update log by using the `Get-WindowsUpdateLog` cmdlet, and look to see if the udpate has been downloaded.

Comment: I did that, I assume I can search it for the kB number? But I could find anything, also scrolled through it to look for anything that looked like it was downloading them but couldn't see anything. So my problem is actually, why are they not downloading, which I have been trying to look into without any luck

Comment: @Jeffrey - To verify, if at all, any updates are being downloaded, you can check the directory `C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download`. If there is any directory inside it with some random string name and there are contents inside that, it hints that the updates are being attempted to download. However, you can rely on the Windows Update GUI, and check if the updates are showing/shown as being downloaded!